# GIT Bash commands produce no output in ConEmu

Tags: windows-7, command-line, conemu, git-bash

I've tried this with `ConEmuPack.141123` and `ConEmuPack.140602`:

As you can see, error messages print fine (like `dir: command not found`), but output from bash commands don't show up.

Does anyone know why I don't see any output from any of the bash commands?

[image]

Comment: It's working on my side. I suppose you need to create an issue on project bugtracker. Some debug logs will be requested at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, guess I found the secret sauce to make this work. My bad for not paying attention to the details.

The solution is to start the shell with `--login -i` paramaters like so:

```
// works
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe --login -i -cur_console:s1THn -new_console:d:d:\src

// doesn't work
C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\sh.exe -cur_console:s1THn -new_console:d:d:\src
```

And now all looks good!

[image]

`--login` stands for login shell, although I have no idea what that means. `-i` I guess is for "interactive"? I couldn't find any official docs about these two arguments, so not sure.

Comment: Actually, I've checked "non login" session as you've shown in the question. And there was no problems with output. So it must be working without `-l -i`. Debug logs are desired.

Comment: But, have you tried the same (without `-l -i`) in the standard Windows console outside of ConEmu?

Comment: Yeah, the same thing works in Windows console without those switches. Without `-l`, it doesn't even come to the linux like prompt, rather `sh.exe"-3.1 $`. This tells me that something's not going thru right. `-i` alone isn't enough, `-l` is needed. I haven't tried just `-l` without `-i` though. How do I capture debug logs?

Comment: Settings -> Debug -> Shell

Comment: Found it under Settings > Info > Debug > Shell. But every time I restart ConEmu, it reverts to Disabled. I see no log output in the folder either.

Comment: And that's why I suggested project tracker. Comments, comments, comments... Do not close Settings window.